# How to add drivers for Touch Monitor (Acer t231hb) and MK802

Tags: drivers, display, android, touch

I am the owner of an Acer T231 touch-capable monitor and a MK802 (mini Android PC). Does anyone know how to get the touch device to work? Are drivers needed for Android?

Comment: Good assumption, so have you tried to locate these drivers?  Do you have references suggesting that this will even work?  What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have only been searching google with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the MK802, see the article [How to re-install MK802 firmware](http://liliputing.com/2012/06/how-to-re-install-mk802-firmware.html) that shows how to install (or reinstall) the firmware and from where. However, only the Rikomagic link
worked for me for downloading LiveSuite and firmware Rev.1. If installing the latest firmware does not fix the problem, then it is probably caused by hardware.

For Android you will probably need to do some patch and recompile work on your kernel as described
in [Multitouch on Android](http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-android-howto.html), since the MK802 is not in the list of [Available multitouch devices](http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html).
As far as I understand from this article, this is easier for Android versions of at least 4.0 (Ice cream sandwich).

Comment: http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?modelId=1248  Its not a travelmate

Comment: I have deleted my bad advice. Have you installed the driver on the monitor support page you linked to ? And on which operating system are you trying to make it work ? The only supported one is Windows, so I don't think there are any drivers for Android.

Comment: .. I have added some words for Android. Hope this helps.

Comment: The MK802 uses ICS. I have been using the monitor on windows for a long time. I just wanted to see if anyone could find a solution for it to work with this MK802 (Android device). Buy my next steps might be to install ubuntu and find out if a working solution exists there.